# ASP.NET Identity 3 cookie authentication not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-3, asp.net-core-1.0

The login code seems to work because `PasswordSignInAsync` return `Succeed`, but when I'm getting the user information **on the next request** by using `User.GetUserName()`, it always return me `null`. And also `User.IsSignedIn()` is also returning `false`.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
{
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            // this code executed and the redirection works fine
            Logger.LogInformation(1, "User logged in.");
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            Logger.LogWarning(2, "RequiresTwoFactor");
        }
        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            Logger.LogWarning(3, "User account locked out.");
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
        return View(model);
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

In the next request, I could not get any information back.

```
Logger.LogWarning(User.Identity.Name ?? "User.Identity.Name is null"); // null
Logger.LogWarning(User.GetUserName() ?? "User.GetUserName() is null"); // null
Logger.LogWarning(User.IsSignedIn() ? "User is signed in" : "User is not signed in"); // not signed in
```

My Startup.cs

```
app.UseIdentity();

services.AddIdentity<CustomAccount, CustomRole>(options =>
{
    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, long>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

**Note: I'm also using `app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication` in the same application, could it be an issue?**

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: any feedback on this topic?, currently i am forced to use `HttpContext.SignInAsync`

Comment: @JSON: I somehow managed to resolve this issue by adding the `certificate` in

Comment: could you please share your code

Comment: @JSON: I added an answer

Answer (score 1):

To anyone who's struggle with this issue. Here's my working code

**Load the cert**

NOTE: I'm importing the certificate to my Azure and load it into my application using **thumbprint** value

```
public X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate()
{
    var certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

    var certCollection = certStore
        .Certificates
        .Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
            "", // Generated by Azure
            false);

    if (certCollection.Count > 0)
    {
        var cert = certCollection[0];
        return cert;
    }

    certStore.Dispose();
    return null;
}
```

**Wire up the identity server**

```
var cert = LoadCertificate();

if (cert == null)
{
    services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddTemporarySigningCredential()
        .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
        .AddConfigurationStore(builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, options => options.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)))
        .AddOperationalStore(builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, options => options.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)));
}
else
{
    services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddSigningCredential(cert)
        .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
        .AddConfigurationStore(builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, options => options.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)))
        .AddOperationalStore(builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, options => options.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)));
}
```

Hope it helps.